# Is it possible to install and use a Ruby distribution alongside a PC with Opscode Chef Client without one affecting the other?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm running chef-client on Windows, and as it happens, the Ruby distribution (1.9.3) embedded in Chef-Client is available system-wide. I believe this is necessary in order to have chef-client function properly? I have tried installing another Ruby distribution (namely, v2.0) but that seems to break Chef-Client.

What I was hoping to achieve is to have chef-client install & configure a Ruby app written against v2.0, so that I can run that app with v2 but have chef-client continue to use the embedded Ruby distribution.

Would that not be possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Comment: No not really, then again, re-reading my question, it wasn't that clear.

Comment: You can always edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's why Opscode is using their [Omnibus packages](https://github.com/opscode/omnibus-ruby), which ships everything required to run Chef.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "gem_binary" attribute to specify the ruby distro:

```
gem_package "somegem" do
  gem_binary "/usr/bin/gem"
  action :install
end
```

The [documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_gem_package.html) describe the parameter as follows:

> **gem_binary**: An attribute for the gem_package provider that is used to specify a gems binary. This attribute is useful when installing Ruby 1.9 gems while running in Ruby 1.8. By default, the same version of Ruby that is used by the chef-client will be installed.